# Handling FaceBook API Tokens (limit and permission)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm crawlers that do a massive collections from Facebook pages and groups.
My main problem is that i get a lots of "Unsupported get request(100)"  and " User request limit reached(17).
I'm using two kind of Tokens: Application-tokens and user-tokens (that i get from another service that connect to Facebook and get the token from the source of the page).
I need some ideas how to handle my Tokens, so i wan't reach this limit. I'm trying to switch to another token when i get the limit error, but since i have some services and each of them have some threads , it doesn't help. 
Thanks for your help,

Comment: if you don´t want to reach limits, limit the amount of api calls. that is the only serious way. switching to different tokens is a workaround that is most likely not allowed - after all you are trying to circumvent limits.

Comment: "massive collections from facebook pages and groups" does sound like scraping btw, which is definitely not allowed.

Comment: I'm understand that scraping, is not allowed, but my superiors wants to see high amount of collections from Facebook. So i do what i can to increase the amounts. How do know that i reach the limit (except by getting the error). What is the limit per hour?

Comment: it does not matter what your superiors want, if it´s not allowed then don´t do it ;) - anyway, as i said, limit the amount of api calls. earlier it was 600 calls per 600 seconds, but they changed it. you can read about it somewhere in the docs.